# Hover animation interruption in Raphael

Tags: javascript, css, svg, hover, raphael

**Problem:**

I'm animating a `<button>` menu icon containing three horizontal lines using Raphael and jQuery. When the mouse enters the target element, the animation begins, but if the cursor moves enough inside the element, the animation abruptly stops, returning to the starting position.

I've placed an absolutely positioned hover target `<label>` above the element containing the Raphael canvas, but the interruption still occurs. Does anyone have thoughts on what could be causing the problem? I appreciate any input.

**jsfiddle:**

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PUg2/82/)

**JavaScript:**

```
var menubtn = Raphael(document.getElementById("menu-btn-cont"), 40, 40);
var menulinetop = menubtn.path("M0 15L40 15").attr({"stroke-width": "2", "stroke" : "#939598"});
var menulinemid = menubtn.path("M0 20L40 20").attr({"stroke-width": "2", "stroke" : "#939598"});
var menulinebtm = menubtn.path("M0 25L40 25").attr({"stroke-width": "2", "stroke" : "#939598"});
// hover
$("#menu-btn").hover(function () {
    menulinetop.animate({"stroke": "black", path: "M0 10L40 10" }, 200);
    menulinemid.animate({"stroke": "black", path: "M0 20L40 20"}, 200);
    menulinebtm.animate({"stroke": "black", path: "M0 30L40 30"}, 200);
}, function() {
    menulinetop.animate({"stroke": "#939598", path: "M0 15L40 15"}, 800, "elastic");
    menulinemid.animate({"stroke": "#939598", path: "M0 20L40 20"}, 800, "elastic");
    menulinebtm.animate({"stroke": "#939598", path: "M0 25L40 25"}, 800, "elastic");
});
```

Comment: Just wondering, it may be worth adding css tag to the question, as I suspect its related to that as well, and maybe some clever css chap will figure it.

Comment: Playing around with your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9PUg2/88/.  CSS hover class confirms that this isn't related to the button not receiving hover mouse events.  Careful testing shows that the problem only occurs if you hover over the button *before* the "unhover" function has completed.  The unhover function completes and the hover function never gets called.

Comment: P.S.  If you can't figure out how to keep hover and unhover functions from conflicting, you could just do it all in CSS, which will always respect the current state, regardless of the timing of previous transitions.  (But it means no elastic easing function, and having the same animation speed for in and out).  http://jsfiddle.net/9PUg2/89/